# MockRetrofit and BehaviorDelegate ignore the OkHttpClient

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm writing an SDK for our MBaaS service. I use `Retrofit2` for my REST calls.

I've an Interceptor (very similar to [this](https://gist.github.com/alex-shpak/da1e65f52dc916716930)) for refreshing an expired token that does a pretty complicated if-else cases. For testing the interceptor, I need to mock our API which I do using `MockRetrofit` library. So far so good! (See end of question for some info on my interceptor class)

Here's the code:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BacktoryClient.BASE_URL)
        .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(new RetryWithRefreshedTokenInterceptor()).build())
        .build();

    NetworkBehavior behavior = NetworkBehavior.create();
    MockRetrofit mockRetrofit = new MockRetrofit.Builder(retrofit)
        .networkBehavior(behavior)
        .build();

    delegate = mockRetrofit.create(AuthApiDefinition.class);
}

@Test
public void testRetryWithRefreshedToken() throws Exception {
    SimpleMock apiMock = new SimpleMock(delegate);
    Response<SomeApiResponse> response = apiMock.someApiCall(<parameters>).execute();
    // assert part
}
```

**The problem is** that `response` object in test method is what it should be (indication that mocking part is OK) but `RetryWithRefreshedTokenInterceptor` interceptor is not being called. So I assume that `MockRetrofit` ignores the `OkHttpClient`.

**Now asking the real question,** is this some kind of bug or I've completely misunderstood the usage of MockRetrofit library? If it was you, how you were testing the interceptor?

---

More info on RetryWithRefreshedTokenInterceptor: It checks if the response code is 401 or not and if so calls a method of our SDK which itself calls a method of our API (here from the mocked API) to get a new token and saves that in persistent storage (The amount of logic handled in API methods used in interceptor is big enough I can't isolate the interceptor to test it with `MockWebserver`)